# KDE stopped working on fedora

Tags: fedora, kde, plasma

Kde Doesn't Work from a long while on fedora , I tried by reinstalling it , browsed very much but no luck . And made new user and logged in kde but again nothing happend . Whenever I log in I get black screen only . And the screenshot is taken on gnome .

Error -
[image: Kde stopped]

Comment: Run https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/check_installed_rpms, post the resulting file here.

Comment: It is very long 18134 lines long, How do I share it

Comment: https://pastebin.com